# ¿Como respetar el formato dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: javascript

Quiero almacenar una fecha a la cual se le sumaron ciertos días, con la función `setDate()`, Ejemplo: `28/02/2018` + 1 día = `01/3/2018`.

Así que agregue un `if` y me agrega el `0` pero al momento de almacenar no funciona

```
fecha_termino.setDate(fecha_termino.getDate() + diasNum);
             //alert(fechaDate.getDate() + '/' + (fechaDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + fechaDate.getFullYear());
   if((fecha_termino.getMonth() + 0) < 10)
    {
      $('#TFecha_termino').val(fecha_termino.getDate() + '/' + '0' +(fecha_termino.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + fecha_termino.getFullYear());
    }
   else
    {
       $('#TFecha_termino').val(fecha_termino.getDate() + '/' + (fecha_termino.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + fecha_termino.getFullYear());
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa el no funciona ? ¿Muestra datos erróneos ? ¿Algún mensaje de error? ¿Como está creando su variable `fecha_termino`?

Comment: No almacena una fecha con un mes diferente, String Out Of Range y var fecha_termino = new Date

Comment: Si lo agrega, por ejemplo si sumo 20/02/2018 + 2 = 22/02/2018 si guarda el dato pero 28/02/2018 + 1 = 1/03/2018 no guarda el dato

Comment: Creo que ya resolví mi duda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que la fecha respete el formato `dd/mm/yyyy` , qué es lo que entiendo que desea realizar , no solo deberá verificar el mes si no también el día para saber cuando agregar el 0 a la izquierda ya que actualmente solo está para el mes, por eso al cambiar al `01` de marzo solo muestra el día **1**.

**Ejm**

```js
var  fecha_termino = new Date(2018,1,28)
var diasMas= 1;
//Incrementamos la fecha
fecha_termino.setDate(fecha_termino.getDate() + diasMas);

let dia = fecha_termino.getDate();
let mes = fecha_termino.getMonth()+1;

//Si el día es menor a 10 , agregamos el 0
if(dia<10)  dia='0'+dia; 
//Si el mes es menor a 10 , agregamos el 0
if(mes<10)   mes='0'+mes;

//asignamos concatenando los valores
document.getElementById('TFecha_termino').value  = dia+ "/"+ mes + "/" + fecha_termino.getFullYear() ;

//Jquery

//$('#TFecha_termino').val(dia+ "/"+ mes + "/" + fecha_termino.getFullYear());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TFecha_termino">
```

Otra forma un poco más rudimentaria es utilizar algunos métodos de los arrays, como son [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice) para extraer toda la fecha , luego `split` para separar la cadena por el `-` , `reverse` para colocar el día al inicio y el año al final , y `join` para concatenar el resultado.

```js
var  fecha_termino = new Date(2018,1,28)
var diasNum = 1;
fecha_termino.setDate(fecha_termino.getDate() + diasNum);
$('#TFecha_termino').val(fecha_termino.toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join ('/'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="TFecha_termino">
```

Comment: Efectivamente esa parte es la que no estaba tomando en cuenta muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: @DavidMelo perfecto , recuerde leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para saber como accionar cuando alguien responde a su pregunta.

Comment: Enseguida la acepto solo estaba corrigiendo mis errores.